# Was the notion of observable really necessary before quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

I'm a mathematician who's been struggling with the search of connections between physics theories and $C^*$-algebras. The most known connection I found was that the observables in quantum mechanics are equivalently described by the elements of the $C^*$-algebra of self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space, a result known as the Gelfand-Naimark-Segal construction.

On the other hand, I found some material on $C^*$-algebras that approaches this result by first understanding the notion of observable under the Hamiltonian formalism of classical mechanics. In this case, the observables are elements of the $C^*$-algebra $C_0(\Gamma)$, where $\Gamma$ corresponds to the phase space.

I personally found the notion of observable in the Hamiltonian formalism to be superfluous, because an observable being a continuous function means that we are able to do our measures with arbitrarilly small error, so, why not consider only the phase space itself? On the other hand, due to the uncertainty principle, it is a really necessary notion when it comes to quantum mechanics.

Therefore, I wonder, with the spirit of a beginner in this field, first of all, if the notion of observable in classical mechanics is really necessary and why so, and second, if there were other physics theories before quantum mechanics in which the role of this notion was as central as it is in quantum mechanics.

Comment: what does "observable" means in your context? For example absolute time in Maxwell-Lorentz theory was not observable, which was quite important for development of physics that led to STR. In fact, science cares only about observable effects and thus distinction between observable and unobservable constructions of our theories was always very important. I am not sure this is what you want though.

Comment: Suppose we allow the Hilbert space to be non-separable. Calling a theory with a non-separable Hilbert space "quantum" might be a stretch, but if we do that, then pretty much every classical theory can be regarded as a special case of quantum theory in which all observables commute with each other and in which we only consider states that are "eigenstates" of all of the observables. That doesn't mean we *must* think of classical physics that way (and I don't know if anybody *did* think of it that way before QM), but we *can*.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm really really a beginner, so I actually don't know much thing about Maxwell-Lorentz theory or QM. I just found it curious that the observables in classic mechanics are continuous functions, so it means that we can measure with an arbitrarily small error. But now I know that there are other examples in which this concept was useful, so thank you very much.